# CentOS will not boot. Error 13

Tags: linux, centos, xenserver

I am having trouble with one of our CentOS servers.

I migrated this server to XenServer, installed a new xen kernel, and performed a mkinitrd with:

```
mkinitrd --omit-scsi-modules --with=xennet --with=xenblk --preload=xenblk initrd-2.6.18-308.4.1.el5xen-no-scsi.img 2.6.18-308.4.1.el5xen
```

Now I am getting an error 13 on boot. Screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/k7js0l41v/

I can still boot with the PAE kernel. Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this? My Grub file looks like:

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-308.4.1.el5xen)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-308.4.1.el5xen ro root=/dev/hdb1 ramdisk_size=256000
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-308.4.1.el5xen-no-scsi.img
title CentOS (2.6.18-308.4.1.el5PAE)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-308.4.1.el5PAE ro root=/dev/hdb1 ramdisk_size=256000
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-308.4.1.el5PAE.img
title CentOS (2.6.18-274.17.1.el5PAE)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-274.17.1.el5PAE ro root=/dev/hdb1 ramdisk_size=256000
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-274.17.1.el5PAE.img
```

Comment: What version of Xen/XenServer are you using? Are you running the VM para-virtualised, or with HVM?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have figured out the cause of this issue and created a tutorial how to fix this for anyone else facing the same problem.

http://zconkle.blogspot.com/2012/04/xenserver-converting-centos-from-hvm-to.html

Comment: We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This ensures that the answer will remain available even if the link goes dead. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.